# ArrayList of Two Classes

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an interface named shape with just a single method that calculates the area of the shape. I then have two classes Shape and Rectangle that implement the shape interface. All of the classes have the appropriate setters, getters, and calcArea method. In main, I have an ArrayList that will store 2 rectangles and two circles. How will I add the rectangles and circles to the array? I have tried to do `shapeArr.` and my methods from Rectangle and Circle don't appear. My code is below and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
public interface Shape {
    public double calcArea();
}


public class Circle implements Shape {
    private int radius;
    private double area;

    public Circle() {
        radius = 1;
    }

    public void setRadius(int r){
        radius = r;
    }

    public int getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double calcArea() {
        area = (Math.PI * (Math.pow(radius, 2)));
        return area;
    }
}


public class Rectangle implements Shape{
    private int height;
    private int width;
    public int area;

    public Rectangle(){
        height = 1;
        width = 1;
    }

    public void setHeight(int h){
        height = h;
    }

    public void setWidth(int w){
        width = w;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public double calcArea() {
        area = (height * width);
        return area;
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShapeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Shape> shapeArr = new ArrayList<Shape>(4);

    }

    public static void displayArea(Shape s) {
        System.out.println("The area of the shape is " + s.calcArea());
    }
}
```

Comment: But what is the problem? In your array object will be available only method of type `Shape`. If you want to use specific methods of subclasses, you need cast your object from object to specific type, but in this case you should exactly know what is type of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be struggling with trying to find a method from a `Shape` type belonging to a `List`.  However, you should be looking for a method in `List` which would allow to add a `Shape` to the collection.  The method you are looking for is `List.add()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Shape> shapeArr = new ArrayList<Shape>(4);
    Circle c = new Circle();
    c.setRadius(10);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    r.setHeight(10);
    r.setWidth(5);

    shapeArr.add(c);
    shapeArr.add(r);
}
```

Now if you want to compute the area of each `Shape` in your `List`, you need only iterate over the collection and call the `calcArea()` method:

```
for (Shape s : shapeArr) {
    System.out.printf("Found a shape with area %.2f", s.calcArea());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, previously I did this method. But I got stuck on the printing of the  areas. I forgot about the for each loop. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest using `printf` instead of `println(... String.format`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast the item from the ArrayList back to the correct type to get the extra fields.

`(Circle)shareArr.get(1)` for example.

You can use the `instanceof` operator to find out what type it is.

```
for(Shape shape: shapeArr)
{

  if(shape instanceof Circle)
  {
    (Circle)shape.circleMethod();
  }
  //same for Rectangle
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you need to make all the methods in Shape. e.g. a Circle has a width/height

Comment: @PeterLawrey a rectangle doesn't have a radius though.

Comment: It has a half width. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey it has half a _diameter_ :)

Comment: Which is also it's width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Since both classes implement the same interface you should have no problem to add these objects to the ArrayList just by calling the add method. After you can call your displayArea method for all the elements in the ArrayList to check their area.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Shape> shapeArr = new ArrayList<Shape>(4);
    shapeArr.add(new Circle());
    shapeArr.add(new Rectangle());
    for (Shape s : shapeArr) {
        displayArea(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this method would be how to set the width and the height or radius in main

Comment: Yes, I just tried to minimize code at maximum to answer clearly your question. If you want that you have to initialize two objects, use the setters to set the height/width (or you could declare another constructor with height and width). Then pass this objects to the add method of the ArrayList.